# How to distinguish between AirPods and connected headphones?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, airpods

I have a need to check if the searched device is an AirPods device. I don’t know how to start. I hope to get your help. Thank you very much!

```
 AVAudioSessionRouteDescription *currentRount = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance].currentRoute;
    AVAudioSessionPortDescription *outputPort = currentRount.outputs[0];
    if ([outputPort.portType isEqualToString:AVAudioSessionPortBluetoothA2DP]) {

    } else {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not much of experience with audio framework of iOS, especially with Bluetooth module. But I did some reading. You could start with this:

[How can I detect whether a HFP or A2DP is connected in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37157252/how-can-i-detect-whether-a-hfp-or-a2dp-is-connected-in-ios)

And the list of BT protocols (good read):

http://monkeycanz.com/hrf_faq/what-are-bluetooth-a2dp-avrcp-hfp-hsp-protocols/

---

And then to answer your question, here's the documentation of Apple for `AVAudioSessionPort`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosessionport?language=objc

From there you can see the constants for that structure, such as:

`AVAudioSessionPortHeadphones` - Output to wired headphones.

`AVAudioSessionPortHeadsetMic` - A wired headset’s built-in microphone.

So there. Imo, if you have these kinds of constants (and please check the other constants too), you have what you're looking for.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer！I thought of a solution to this problem.You can filter other devices by scanning Uid with Bluetooth.